# The plugin `webview_flutter_android` doesn't have a main class defined

Tags: flutter

I'm installing the plugin but I'm getting this error, I couldn't find a solution on the internet

I tried other plugins and got the same error with them.

```
The plugin `webview_flutter_android` doesn't have a main class defined in 
C:\Users\ykyaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\flutter\.pub- 
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter_android- 
2.8.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\WebViewFlutterPlugin.java or 
C:\Users\ykyaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\flutter\.pub- 
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter_android- 
2.8.2\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\WebViewFlutterPlugin.kt. This 
is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter` or 
`mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to 
any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider 
using a different plugin in the meanwhile. 
exit code 1
```

Comment: Your question is really confusing. What do you want to do? You have a link and you just want to open the link inside your app's webview?

Comment: yes i want to do that but i get this error